# delegate add and remove

Tags: c#, delegates

I wrote a sample example ,

When I created a delegate instance like below

```
AddFunctions d1 += new AddFunctions(Function1);
```

I got a compilation error and hence += was removed and created in this way

```
AddFunctions d1 = new AddFunctions(Function1);
```

I was just curious to know , Why it is not allowed to have multicast(+=) when a single delegate instance is created?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace Delegates
{
    public delegate void AddFunctions();

    class Program
    {

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            AddFunctions d1 = new AddFunctions(Function1);
            d1 -= d1;
            d1();
        }

        static void Function1()
        {
        }

        static void Function2()
        {
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is for exactly the same reason that you aren't allowed to have:

```
int i += 1;
```

The `+=` operator, for delegates, is a combination. It is allowed with events (where it maps to the `add` accessor) and fields/variables (as long as the variable is assigned) (where it maps to `Delegate.Combine`)

It you **really** want to use `+=`, try:

```
AddFunctions d1 = null;
d1 += Function1;
```

However, the following is easier:

```
AddFunctions d1 = Function1;
```

Comment: Small side-note: in the case of field-like events, what happens *inside* the `add` accessor is compiler-specific, and changes for the MS compiler between C# 3 and C# 4

Answer (score 3):

The following works, and the `= null` initialization is required. That also explains why `+=` cannot be used in a decalaration.

```
 AddFunctions d1 = null;
 d1 += new AddFunctions(Function1);
```

It has little to do with delegates though, you get the same error for

```
 int i += 1;
```

Answer (score 2):

The `+=` operator combines an existing delegate with another delegate; `d1 += d2` is equivalent to `d1 = d1 + d2`. But in your case, `d1` is not initialized yet, so it doesn't make sense to combine it with another delegate. You need to initialize it first with `=`.

Comment: how does the compiler handles this?

Comment: @Raghav55, following a declaration, the compiler expects either an initializer (introduced by `=`), the declaration of another variable of the same type (introduced by `,`), or the end of the instruction (`;`). `+=` is not an expected token in that context.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
AddFunctions d1 = null;
d1 += Function1;
```

if you want to have multicast.